# How to update large database in mysql database using cronJobs

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, cron, guzzle

I am very thank full if anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Detail: I have a mysql table where 110000+ record stored with Unique application(column) number.
Now there is Detail API which will take only 1 application number at a time in URI parameter and return details of that application number it will take Approx 1 min to respond for now.

Now i need to update that records(multiple column) using Cron Job Scheduling to always updated record in database.
and it will progressively update.

Flow: Get application number from database -> Call detail API -> update there record on database.

Issue: there is large number of record in database so we can not call API for all application number in ones.

I am using Laravel 7 and Guzzle HTTP client 7.2 [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client)  for API calling.

Any suggestion are welcome !

**Update:** **(Tested)** I am thinking to do something like this and agree with @bhucho comment to call cron in every 15 minute

We create one more column in table for last_updated_id default 1
and we will write a query to fetch application number something like and get 100 or 500 records in one slab using Laravel take methods from here [Database Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries)

```
$latestIdInColumn = myTableClassRef::max(last_updated_id);

$applications = myTableClassRef::select('application_number)->where('id', '>', $latestIdInColumn)
->take(100)
->get()->toArray();
```

Here we call detail API and update for each application number, when there is last application update done we will store that id in last_updated_id.

When again cron call we have that last_updated_id so we will apply same filter in next query where id '>' $latestIdInColumn. now we will get next 100/500 records where id is greater then $latestIdInColumn.

```
if ( $applications  )
{
  For all other available id
} else {
  when record not found.
  Here we will reset the last_updated_id = 1
}
```

Now function will fetch from id  1.

- *It is not tested yet i just planing to do this, i am happy to have
  feedback on this.*

**Note: Now API not taking 1Min to respond I resolved this issue.**

**Update 2:** It is working good.

Comment: looks like task scheduling https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Comment: It should not take a minute to fetch 1 record - do you have appropriate indexes in place? and 110000 records is not big.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond Yes but i am asking how it is possible we need to call API for each application number and need to update  detail in database.

Comment: @P.Salmon Ok i  will check for timing, but i need to call API for each application number and need to update there record in database.

Comment: use cronjobs & run it as queues every 15 min or so, it will run every 15 min till the queue is cleared, you can also use superviser flow to keep a track of failed jobs & failed jobs are handled accordingly or run again

Comment: @bhucho agree with your 15 min cronjob and update my plan in above question according to this i am happy if you review this.

Comment: I do think your procedure will work out, seems ok to me